# ostream& operator<< segfaults without flush()

Tags: c++, operators, iostream

I have a custom class for which I've defined a custom cast `operator char()`, call it `A`. Now, say I want an array of this class but with added functionality so I define a new class `B` to achieve this with a member variable `array` of type `std::vector<A>`.

One of the things I want `B` to handle is printing its data to screen so I create a `friend` function

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const B& b)
{
   // invoking custom cast works fine here
   for(int i=0;i<array.size();++i) out.put((char)array[i]); 
   // without the following out.flush() we get segfault
   out.flush()
}
```

For some reason when I omit the `out.flush()` statement at the end it causes a segmentation fault. I would rather not have the flush in there because it should be up to the user to choose when to flush the stream (I believe?) so can anybody please clarify why it crashed without it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code of `A` too? It could be that your `operator char()` makes a mistake somewhere and you get the punishment later. The fact that you get lucky when calling `out.flush()` could be because you call a function, modifying a possible mess on the stack, turning it in to a more tolerable mess!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return something there. Certainly the stream you've been provided, so you should:

```
return out;
```

as the last line of the operator. Note that, maybe by chance, calling `out.flush()` made some register (say EAX) to hold the value of the stream, thus being returned (as per standard calling convention), and this is what the caller was expecting. *BUT* you have to add that last `return` for sure.

Comment: That's it! That's what I get for late-night coding. Irritating that the compiler didn't warn me about no return in non-void. Also, cheers for possible explanation of why `out.flush()` doesn't crash.

Comment: Glad to help! :) You see, some say having programmed in assembler doesn't count, but it does :)

Comment: In fact, `flush` also returns the stream, so actually it is as if the function actually returned the stream, but again, the `return` is necessary.

Comment: Indeed, and my lesson for today is even for tiny proof-of-concept pieces of code use `-Wall`.